# assigning multiple users to a task errors

Tags: force.com, activities

I'm not sure how this feature of SF is supposed to behave. I want to be able to add multiple users to the task, **specifically when i want to lookup and add a user with one last name THEN  do a lookup for a user with anouther.**

1. I'm on a task, and click the lookup for  assigned to.
2. clicking the multiple users tab, changing to users, search for one user and add but as soon as they search for another it removes the first not searching but scrolling through will allow multiple selections

Is there another way to add multiple users? Is there a bug in SF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue: [Summer '13: "selected members" values in "multi user lookup" do not stick when multiple searches are performed](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Sxj5AAC)

Comment: ugh, i did a search for that, and I must have missed it! Thanks!

Comment: This issue has been marked as "fixed" on the known issues site. I can confirm it is fixed in my org that was affected as well.